# Netstat and ss doesn't see connection

Tags: kubernetes, tcpdump, netstat, network-namespace

I'm trying to find which application running on Kubernetes cluster is using a specific port to communicate with RabbitMQ cluster. On RabbitMQ I see that connection is coming from 192.168.1.10:34226. 192.168.1.10 is one of Kubernetes nodes. After logging in to 192.168.1.10 I checked if connection is established from that node by tcpdump command `tcpdump -i eth0 port 34226`. I see traffic with both directions. Now I'm trying to find which process is making this connection. First I tried netstat:

`netstat -tapn | grep 34226`

and it found nothing. Then I tried ss but still nothing. Connection is established, with tcpdump I can see heartbeat packets sent to RabbitMQ and response from RabbitMQ. But netstat and ss don't report established connection.

**UPDATE 1**

I found that is something related to network namespaces. My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171909/when-using-docker-established-connections-dont-appear-in-netstat) but I need to find PID of process which make connection from 34226 port.

Comment: Try `kubectl get svc`, and look for the port. That will lead you to which `POD` is the `Service` exposing. `kubectl get po` will show you list of pods. Keep in mind that if they are not on a default namespace you might have to add `--all-namespaces=true`

Comment: It's not matter of exposed ports but ports used to initiate connection from container.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific or describe it in a different way. If you are looking a way to login to a `POD` inside a cluster you can do `kubectl exec -it <POD_NAME> --/bin/bash`

Comment: I think that I described problem understandable. I know how to run command in container. I'm trying to find which container is making connection on outgoing port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After couple of weeks I found answer. I needed to run `netstat -tapn` in all namespaces with following command:

```
sudo ip -all netns exec netstat -tapn | grep 34226
```

Now I have PID number of process which start tcp connection from 34226 port.

Comment: Not working for me on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Maybe you dont have any namespaces

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 18 either. I'm running a docker container listening on port 3003 (via docker run -p 3003:3003) and it doesn't show up. It *does show* when I find the container PID and invokes netstat like this: `nsenter -t 13401 -n netstat -tapn`

Comment: More information can be found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522435/63528 (the custom script works well)

Comment: Docker doesn't use network namespaces. The question is related to Kubernetes which deals with networks differently.

Comment: worked fine on GKE nodes